# Select from another table every 12 records returned

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select from a table, then select 1 random row from another table every 12th record?

I've searched but can't find anything close to what I am looking for.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Its a rather odd requirement. I doubt any database would come with that pre configured just in case you wandered along. And one _Small Point_ One row every 12th row is not actually random!

Comment: @RiggsFolly "Every 12" sounds like the original table is by month, and then they want to add an additional record each year. Which suggests a joining the second table with a `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date)... from table1` subquery, and then unioning that with the original table.

Comment: The reason you cannot find anything is because rows in a relational database have no number or order. This means there's no 12th row after another row. However, you can create an order yourself, based on the values in one or more columns, and that would allow you to pick the rows you want.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware or use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

Comment: This question sounds like a task that should be solved in two simpler queries, then the results from the two queries combined using application code.

Comment: John. I guess it is down to you now to provide a more specific definition of what you are trying to do, so people can attempt an answer

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll add more meat. I have a table with information that I want displayed (table 1). I have another table that will show advertising text (table 2). Every 12th row of table 1 I would like to display 1 row from table 2 which will be an advert.

Comment: Then I agree with @BillKarwin. Do that in the code that creates the table, not in the query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I'll do.

Comment: After many years of writing clever, complex SQL queries, I keep going back to the Kernighan quote: _"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."_ It's usually best to keep code as simple as possible. Code maintainability should be a design goal.